# C++ - A few questions about throwing exceptions

Tags: c++, exception

I've got a few questions about throwing exceptions in C++.
From what I know about them...

An exception can be thrown from within the main() function. Any block of code that can throw an exception in the main() function should be surrounded by try and catch statements as follows

```
    void foo(//args) {
     if (...) {
      throw "Error reached";
     } ...

    int main() {
     ...
     try {
      //Code that can throw an excpetion
     } catch(const char* msg) (
      cerr << msg << endl;
     } 
     ...
    }
```

**In the example above, why is the argument to the catch a const char *. Doesn't C++ allow for strings? Also, is it possible to throw an exception that isn't a const char *, like an int? or a char?**

**Does throwing an exception in foo, terminate the foo function?**

**Are there cases where you could put the try and catch statements in the same function as the throw?**

Sorry if these are basic questions.
Thanks SO

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that the exception that is thrown in foo "Error reached", is that a string or a const char *, because I think that is what I need to put in the catch statement as a parameter.

Comment: You can edit your question rather than providing errata in the comments.

Comment: @The_Questioner Added an example below, HTH.

Answer (score 6):

> why is the argument to the catch a const char *

Because you threw string literal which decays to `const char*`. In short, you catch what you throw.

> Doesn't C++ allow for strings?

It does, but to catch string, you need to throw string in first place.

> is it possible to throw an exception that isn't a const char *,

You can throw literally anything. It is a good idea to throw special exception classes, like `std::exception` and derived from it.

> Does throwing an exception in foo, terminate the foo function?

Yes, it does.

> Are there cases where you could put the try and catch statements in the same function as the throw?

If you want, you can do that. There are not much cases where doing it is a good idea.

It looks like you need to get a good book and read chapter about exceptions. In the meantime [this super-FAQ entry](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions) might help you/

Comment: Thanks for that. I've got a follow-up question if you don't mind. If any string literal I throw decays into a const char*, then how do I throw a string? I'll look into some good C++ books after this.

Comment: @The_Questioner `throw std::string("some string");`

Comment: Or `throw "some string"s;` !!

Comment: @PreferenceBean That however means that you first need to bring the namespace `std::literals::string_literals` into scope.

Answer (score 2):

You can throw an object of any type.

**EDIT:** (Hopefully I got this right now)
What you have done is throw a C-string, which is of type `const char[13]` in this case. C-Arrays will decay to pointers to their first element, in this case a pointer of type `const char*`.

Typically what you want to do is throw a predefined exception object. They can be found in header `<stdexcept>` and are *derived* from a base class `std::exception`. The derived exception classes are for instance `std::logic_error`, `std::range_error`, `std::bad_alloc` etc.

Their constructors take a string as argument, so you can for instance

```
throw std::logic_error{"Negative values not allowed."};
```

This message can be accessed in a catch statement like this:

```
catch(std::exception &e) // capture reference to base class
{
    std::cout << e.what() << '\n'; // what() of derived is called, since virtual
}
```

If an exception is caught, so-called *stack unwinding* takes place. You can then deal with the error locally, or rethrow the exception. Only when an exception is thrown and never caught, std::terminate() is called an the program aborted.

You can put try/catch statements anywhere. However, remember what the term "exception" actually means. Cases that can easily dealt with using a simple conditional expression `if (n < 0) break;` or something like that, don't need the exception treatment. Especially if you can realistically expect this kind of unwanted condition to be true often. Then it is not something "exceptional".

If you decide to deal with an error using exceptions and they can **not** be treated locally, you may put try/catch clauses around the beginning and end of main().

Since you can put **several** catch statements directly after a try statement, you can then begin to deal with more specific errors, or simply catch **anything** via `catch(...) { //... }`.

This is all described in great detail (including pointers on **when** and **when not** to use it, in the [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions).

**EDIT:** Here's an example that makes use of try/catch statements. However, not an exception object is caught, but an int (errno). Just to show, that you can really throw/catch anything you like. Let `process_several_files()` be a function somewhere nested in your code:

```
 std::vector<std::string> process_several_files(std::vector<std::string> const& files)
 {
      std::vector<std::string> contents{};
      contents.reserve(files.size()); // files contains file names from user input
      for (auto const& file : files)
      {
           try
           {
                contents.emplace_back(get_file_contents(file.c_str())); // A "C like" function. get_file_contents() will throw "errno", if a file does not exist
           }
           catch(int err)
           {
                std::cerr << "***Error while opening " << file << " : " << std::strerror(err) << "***\n";
                continue;                   // "scope" didn't change, just keep iterating!
           }
      }
      return contents;
 }
```

Comment: A string literal is not of type `char*`. Nor is it of type `const char*`.

Comment: Saw that literally the first second I posted it. Sorry.

Comment: I can't see any revision in the post's history (including the current one) that correctly identifies the type of string literals.

Comment: Ah ok, I misunderstood. I meant char literal and even this is probably not correct. C-String should be OK though. Hopefully, this time.

Comment: The sentence "What you have done is throw a C-string, which is of type "const char*"." is still not correct. A C string is an array, not a pointer.

Comment: Alright. I would be inclined to say it's of type `char[]`, which _decays_ into a pointer of type `const char*`, but maybe that is still wrong?

Comment: @mbw: it's almost correct, but it's `char const[N]`, and that one then decays into the pointer