# Exception in c++ not showing throw to cout

Tags: c++, macos, exception, terminal, throw

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
int num = 1;

try
{
    if (num != 0)
    {
        throw "num is not 0!";
    }
}
catch (char *x)
{
    cout << x << endl;
}
}
```

I want this code to print "num is not 0!" to cout but when i run it i get `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type char const*
Abort trap: 6` as output from the terminal. Am I misunderstanding how exceptions work or is there some other problem?

Comment: The message states `type: char const* `

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528780/c-a-few-questions-about-throwing-exceptions?rq=1

Comment: Maybe you are confused as to what the `throw "num is not 0!";` statement does. It's not the one that outputs the string literal on the standard output. The catch block does that. Also this compiles with Visual Studio while it does not with GCC. String literal is of type `const char*` not `char*`.

Comment: Just saying; as a general rule of thumb, exceptions should always be caught by const reference `catch (const& whatever)`.

Comment: Prefer instead to throw `std::runtime_error{"num is not 0!"}` and log it with `std::exception::what()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you throw a string literal and it cannot be bound to `char*`. Rather it can be bound to `char const*`.

Pedantically, the type of `"num is not 0!"` is `char const[14]`, however, in `throw` expression [the array decays to a pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay) to its first element.